# Configuring jest snapshots pretty format

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Jest snapshots produce format like:

```
<div
  className="forecastChart">
  <div>
    <div
      className="dow">
      Tue
    </div>
    ...
```

I'd prefer a more human-readable / human-composed style where tags with single attributes aren't indented:

```
<div className="forecastChart">
  <div>
    <div className="dow">
      Tue
    </div>
    ...
```

Is there a way to do this? There doesn't appear to be an option in [pretty-format](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/pretty-format).

Comment: did you happen to find an answer to this? thanks!

Comment: No. I didn’t. I haven’t looked at recent changes in Jest though.

Comment: Vue has serializer that solves this issue, might be worth looking into source code to adopt for vanilla html too https://github.com/tjw-lint/jest-serializer-vue-tjw